# Trying to enhancing data validtion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just started learning asp.net. In the asp.net application I am working on, I used the database first approach. My question, if I want to add data annotations, which is the preferred approach to do it. Should I update my models file or should I update the database table? I apologize if it is a very basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Add annotation on model this will be right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind explaining why this approach is the right one?

Comment: Because you use CODE FIRST APPROACH. so you work with model not with database.Therefore, you validate the model in simple words code,

Comment: I used database first approach. I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean